# Does Jesus do for Gentiles what the Torah does for Jews?

Tags: paul-apostle, judaism

In [this review](http://www.tabletmag.com/jewish-arts-and-culture/books/20214/who-was-paul) of the book *Paul was Not a Christian* by Pamela Eisenbaum, Jewish magazine author Judith Schulevitz writes:

> *Paul Was Not a Christian* is the title of a book published this fall; what he was—and never stopped being—according to New Testament scholar Pamela Eisenbaum and the revisionists she echoes was a law-abiding Jew.

And later:

> Paul is supposed to be the genius who overcame Jewish particularism and invented religious universalism, but the new Paul [of *Paul was not a Christian*] didn’t do that. He didn’t believe that the Jewish God stopped being Jewish. Nor did he think Jesus superseded God’s covenant with his chosen people. [Paul taught that] What Jesus mainly did was die for the *goyim*: “What Torah does for Jews, Jesus does for gentiles,” writes Eisenbaum.

Are there proponents of a Christian viewpoint that paraphrase or conclude from Paul's writing the same as Eisenbaum: "*what the Torah does for Jews, Jesus does for Gentiles*"?

Do any conclude from Paul's writings that Jesus has a role, position, ministry, office, or authority in the *kosmos* in addition to being the way for Gentiles to enter the Kingdom of God?

Any answers should include citations of Paul's writings and commentary on them.

Comment: So the book is claiming Jesus only died for gentiles? I'm not sure what you're asking... if anything Paul wrote supports that idea?

Comment: Yes, and "according to whom?"

Comment: Well that's not really a Christian theory... but who knows maybe there's some sect that thinks so.

Comment: @curiousdannii From what I understand (I haven't read it yet), the book claims that Paul was not encouraging Jews to change, only to accept Jesus as a way for Gentiles to enter into the _Kingdom to Come_, a privilege Torah-abiding Jews already possess.

Comment: The question also welcomes dissenting commentaries.

Comment: Anyone arguing that Paul was an orthodox Jew to the day of his death needs to go back to gradeschool and learn the alphabet, because they obviously can't read.

Comment: @davidbrainerd I disagree. Paul was given the revelation of the Messiah of Israel. Messiah revealed that for a Jew, to continue with him _was_ orthodoxy (original, correct teaching and practice), Judaism apart from Messiah is _apostate_, not the true and correct teaching and practice for the sons of Abraham.

Comment: @Andrew, Semantics. I meant "Orthodox Jew" in the sense that the book you cited argues, not in some redefined Christian sense. They're pretending in the book that Paul believed Jews could be saved without Jesus, and its clear he did not.  In fact, Paul was probably more rabidly against that idea than Matthew. You can get the impression from Matthew that a Jew who follows the law pretty well might be saved...but Paul categorically denies this, particularly in Romans.

Comment: @davidbrainerd quite right

Comment: Maybe you should define the concept of "what the Torah does for Jews," before asking if Jesus does the same for Gentiles.  Because from a generic Protestant perspective I can see many people scratching their heads saying either "the Torah does nothing for the Jews" or "the Torah condemns the Jews" (which the only answer so far actually says!).  The book I guess would say the Torah does many things, including unify the Jews, give them something to reverence in the extreme, provide a moral example, provide a connection to God, etc.

Comment: I suppose the answerers should be able to address that from some source.

Comment: You talk about Paul and then you ask about Jesus. Maybe rephrase your question - 'Does Paul do for Gentiles ... ?' Jesus showed the way of an 'easy' conversion to Judaism and an affordable way to remain within Judaism. Paul then expanded on that beyond the Jews. Jesus ONLY taught a form of Judaism for Jews who could no longer keep the laws due to mostly financial restraints while clarifying contentious points of law. These lapsed Jews were sometimes called Greeks. He never instructed Gentiles to be taught - that Paul did on his own. (The role of the Hellenist synagogue is unclear in all this.)

Comment: @gideonmarx The question is re _Paul's teaching about Jesus_.

Comment: *"Paul Was Not a Christian"* the title alone might convince me to pick up the book at the stand, because I'd say "Paul was the *first* Christian".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book the question refers to does not seem to have a correct understanding of the gospel. There is only one gospel which is for both Jews and Gentiles, and Paul clearly taught that.

The beginning of Romans (1:18-3:20) shows that everyone, both Jews and Gentiles, are condemned by their sin. At the very end Paul says what he thought the purpose of the law was:

> Obviously, the law applies to those to whom it was given, for its purpose is to keep people from having excuses, and to show that the entire world is guilty before God. For no one can ever be made right with God by doing what the law commands. The law simply shows us how sinful we are. (Romans 3:19-20, NLT)

So "What Torah does for Jews" is condemn them!

What Jesus did, through dying on the cross and coming back to life again, is provide a way for us to receive God's righteousness. This is what the following verses say:

> But now God has shown us a way to be made right with him without keeping the requirements of the law, as was promised in the writings of Moses and the prophets long ago. We are made right with God by placing our faith in Jesus Christ. And this is true for everyone who believes, no matter who we are.
>
> For everyone has sinned; we all fall short of God’s glorious standard. Yet God freely and graciously declares that we are righteous. He did this through Christ Jesus when he freed us from the penalty for our sins. For God presented Jesus as the sacrifice for sin. People are made right with God when they believe that Jesus sacrificed his life, shedding his blood. This sacrifice shows that God was being fair when he held back and did not punish those who sinned in times past, for he was looking ahead and including them in what he would do in this present time. God did this to demonstrate his righteousness, for he himself is fair and just, and he declares sinners to be right in his sight when they believe in Jesus. (Romans 3:21-26, NLT)

Several times Paul says very explicitly that the gospel is for both the Jews and Gentiles:

> For I am not ashamed of this Good News about Christ. It is the power of God at work, saving everyone who believes—the Jew first and also the Gentile. (Romans 1:16, NLT)
>
> There will be trouble and calamity for everyone who keeps on doing what is evil—for the Jew first and also for the Gentile. But there will be glory and honor and peace from God for all who do good—for the Jew first and also for the Gentile. For God does not show favoritism. (Romans 2:9-11, NLT)

Comment: TL;DR: "Jesus does for both Jews and Gentiles what the Torah does not do for either: He saves them from their sins."